# Failover to a readable secondary

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Is it possible to failover to a readable secondary (which always has an asynchronous-commit mode) using `FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

See also: [Perform a Forced Manual Failover of an Always On Availability Group (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/perform-a-forced-manual-failover-of-an-availability-group-sql-server)